# How to use filter with two Observables and return only one in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs-pipeable-operators, combinelatest

I have a part of code that checks if two observables are up to date and returns the second observable if they are:

```
combineLatest([$source1, $source2]).pipe(
  filter(([source1, source2]) => source1.id === source2.id),
  map(([_, source2]) => source2)
);
```

How could I simplify the code?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have right now? It seems pretty brief and expressive. You could move it into a custom operator to hide it in a bigger context, but other than that I don't see much to do here.

Comment: I'm just considering if I am able to refactor this code. Maybe there is an rxjs operator that does this stuff and I don't know the operator.

Comment: It looks simple enough to me, I can't think of a much simpler approach at least. Does it work like it's supposed to do?

Comment: Possibly `groupBy(source => source.id, identity)`. It doesn't accomplish the exact same thing, but it might do what you want too.

Comment: Oh and you'd need to use concat or something like that instead of combineLatest for that to work.

Comment: If you feel it's too long, I would move it into a custom operator and be done with it. Otherwise I would leave it as is — it expresses clearly what it does.

Comment: It works like it's supposed to do. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

you can use iif rxjs operator, so you can subscribe to one observable or another based on a condition

```
combineLatest([$source1, $source2]).pipe(
 mergeMap(
     ([s1, s2]) => iif(() => s1.id === s2.id, of(s2), EMPTY)
 )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the top of your pipe to be source2 (which means you don't have any weird stream mapping), and if you want your code to read in plain english, then you can write your code like this.

```ts
emitWhenSourcesAreEqual$ = sample(
  combineLatest([source1$, source2$]).pipe(
    filter(([source1, source2]) => source1?.id === source2?.id)
  )
);
output$ = source2$.pipe(emitWhenSourcesAreEqual$);
```